# Php how does stream_select work?

Tags: php, sockets

```
public function __construct() {
    if (!$this->Listen()) {
        throw new Exception;
    }
     while (1) {
        $read = $this->master;
        $mod_fd = stream_select($read, $w = null, $e = null, 5, 00);
        if ($mod_fd === FALSE) {
            throw new Exception;
        }
        foreach ($read as $feed => $stream) {
            if ($stream === $this->master['main']) {
                $conn = stream_socket_accept($this->master['main']);
                $this->master[count($this->master)] = $conn;
            } else {
                $this->ReadStream($feed, $stream);
            }
        }
    }
}

private function Listen() {
    $socket = stream_socket_server("tcp://0.0.0.0:6001", $errno, $errstr);
    if ($errstr != '') {
        return false;
    }
    $this->master['main'] = $socket;
    return true;
}
```

My understanding is that `stream_select` will fill `$read` with the streams that have data available for reading.

My intention was to read each stream in `$read` one after the other but something really screwey is going on inside `ReadStream` where sometimes the data appears to be coming from a different stream than I expected.

Perhaps `$read` is being modified by `stream_select` before I got a chance to loop through them? But I thought that everyting in the process will happen asynchronously so now I'm totally confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a socket, therefore you need to use `socket_select`, not `stream_select`. The later is for file streams.

You need to call `socket_read` to get any data from it.

The PHP manual has some create examples in the comment section.

Comment: using this method means I have to switch to `socket_create` instead of `stream_socket_server` and socket methods like `socket_read` instead of `fread` etc but it did work so +1 and thanks